# Is it possible to connect with php to a named instance mssql

Tags: php, sql-server

Is it possible to connect from php 7.1 to a mssql server named instance with msphpsql
https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql

they say Connection using named instances using '' is not supported.
what do they mean with ''?

Comment: What happens in the server name if you provide the named instance? $serverName = "yourServername\namedinstancename";

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired in /var/www/html/Functions/sqlFunc.php:120 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/Functions/sqlFunc.php(120): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:server=t...', 'sa-service', '*******') #1 /var/www/html/Functions/sqlFunc.php(26): OpenConnectionAdmin() #2 {main}    if i use sql server that has a default instance it works

Comment: Let's see the connection string.

Comment: $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database = $database", $uid, $pwd);   
      $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  

both pdo and sqlsrv_connect are not working

 $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);

Comment: Are you able to connect yourServername\namedinstancename via SSMS?

Comment: Yes i am, i have 3 named instance server and all 3 i can connect trough sql management studio

Answer (score 1):

Named Instances run on different ports. Instead of specifying the named instance, you can specify the alternate port number. The port number can be found in the instance's log file.